# I don't get how the answer to this problem works, its a practice mathcon problem.

Tags: geometry

The answer to this problem is c. I don't get how that is the answer.
[This is the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qQrtf.png)
[image: Theproblem]

Comment: Does this help?  Note it's a non quantitative version of the problem, but the answer includes calculations and helpful reasoning. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3858389/geometry-height-of-water-in-tilted-canister

Answer (score 2):

$AB$ is the diameter of the base, so the area of the base is $9\pi$ cm$^2$.  Whatever angle the can is tilted at the volume to raise the level $2$ cm in slant height is the same.  You are raising the level $2$ cm parallel to the axis over the area of the bottom.  This means the volume of interest is $18 \pi$ cm$^3$

Comment: I had to read it three times, but finally I see what you are saying and of course it is correct.

Answer (score 2):

Ross Millikan posted an answer long before I finished tinkering with that picture, but here is my version.

[image: revised picture]

The volume in question is enclosed by the ellipse with large diameter EF, and the ellipse with large diameter GD (which is just a copy of the first ellipse, shifted up to the point when water overflows). By Cavalieri's principle, this is the same as the volume of a cylinder where the base is the ellipse with large diameter EF, and the height is $h=$ the distance from point F to the top ellipse (with large diameter GD). So, all this is less elegant, but if $t$ is the acute angle between the horizontal and AF, then the large diameter of these ellipses is the length of AF which is $\dfrac6{\sin(t)}$. The small and large radii are respectively $a=\dfrac62=3$ and $b=\dfrac6{2\sin(t)}=\dfrac3{\sin(t)}.$ The area of the ellipse is
$S=\pi ab=\pi\cdot3\cdot\dfrac3{\sin(t)}=\dfrac{9\pi}{\sin(t)}.$ The height $h$ (see picture) is $h=2\sin(t)$, so the volume in question is product of the area $S$ and the height $h$, so it is $\dfrac{9\pi}{\sin(t)}\cdot2\sin(t)=18\pi.$